# Verbos ser/estar + localização

Tags: gramática, locuções-adverbias, localização, ser-estar

Me deparei com as seguintes frases:

1. O cinema é distante.
2. A ponte está muito próxima.
3. O hotel é por ali.
4. A biblioteca está perto do bar.

Entendo que usar ser ou estar em qualquer dessas frases não alteraria o sentido, mas fui procurar algo que explique isso e vi que para localização devemos usar o verbo ser.

Existe alguma outra regra que explique o motivo de serem usados os dois verbos de modo intercambiável ou o uso do verbo estar seria informal nesse caso?

Comment: A localização é um assunto complicado mas  não existe nenhuma regra. Além disso, eu não usaria nem ser ou estar. Usaria: ficar em português. Quem diz que os dois verbos se usam de modo intercambiável?? Algun desses gurus nadando nesses mares? Credo. :)

Comment: Em português (é não tradução literal a partir do inglês), se fala O cinema fica longe daqui.

Answer (score 3):

Eu usaria "2. A ponte está muito próxima" se estivesse caminhando em direção a ela, portanto qualquer informação de localização seria *transitória* (por isso "está").

O "4. A biblioteca está perto do bar" eu *não usaria*, preferindo "é" ou "fica". Este uso de "está" para localização me soa mais como espanhol, mas pode haver regiões de fala portuguesa que também utilizem esta construção.

Já as frases 1 e 3 me parecem boas. Na frase 1, informalmente, eu diria "longe" em vez de "distante", mas o uso de "é" me soa bem. "O cinema fica longe" seria também uma alternativa.

Answer (score 3):

Resumo:
Para distâncias tendemos a usar ser, mas em alguns casos estar se a distância é referente a algo transitório - por exemplo talvez durante uma viagem de carro.

## Regra base

A regra base é que:

- *Ser* é para estados **permanentes**, "sou peludo" - de maneira permanente.
- *Estar* é para estados **transitórios**, "estou sujo" - só agora, neste momento, ou no presente próximo.

Quando apanho uma gripe estou doente.
Quando tenho uma doença crónica, sou doente.

Quando bebo uma garrafa de vinho, estou (fico) bêbado - só agora, hoje.
Quando bebo uma garrafa de vinho todos os dias, sou bêbado - sempre.

## Uso

### Uso geral

Geralmente um tipo de coisa é permanente ou transitória, e por isso é usada com um verbo ou outro:

- O cinema é distante, é longe daqui.
- A ponte é muito próxima (daqui).
- O hotel é por ali.
- A biblioteca é perto do bar.

E:

- *Sou* peludo.
- *Estou* sujo, quero tomar banho.
- *Sou* inteligente.
- O restaurante *é* caro.
- A biblioteca *é* longe de minha casa.

### Subtilezas

Mas a língua permite nuances detalhadas.

Usando os verbos ser e estar, parecidos mas diferentes, imprimimos subtilezas e pormenores precisos à nossa linguagem: às vezes ligeiros, às vezes imensos.

Não digamos ao chefe, na festa da empresa, que é bêbado! Bebeu talvez um pouco, estará ligeiramente tocado...

#### Peludo?

Digamos que o camarada Carlos Marques usa barba farta, mas eu rapo a barba. Então:

> O Carlos Marques é barbudo. **É peludo**.
> Eu não... normalmente. Mas tenho-me desleixado estes dias, e estou com a precisar de rapar a cara, que **estou peludo** e não me agrada.

Usamos "ser peludo" para falar de algo permanente (uma característica, um estado).
E usamos "estar peludo" para falar de algo transitório (uma característica, um estado) - o verbo estar transmite a informação que o estado atual "peludo" é algo transitório, e indica que o estado normal é não-peludo.

#### Sujo?

Por se enlamearem, achamos (injustamente!) que os porcos *são* sujos.

Por se limparem constantemente, achamos que os gatos são asseados; então se vemos um gato enlameado, dizemos que *está* sujo.

## Exemplos da pergunta

A pergunta foca em casos de distâncias, posições de *coisas imóveis*:

- O cinema é distante.
- A ponte *está** muito próxima.
- O hotel é por ali.
- A biblioteca *está** perto do bar.

Geralmente, **estas posições e distâncias são absolutas e por isso pedem o verbo "ser"**:

- O cinema é/fica longe.
- A ponte *é/fica* muito perto.
- O hotel é por ali.
- A biblioteca *é* perto do bar.

Mas quando estamos **num contexto de movimento, a característica referente às distâncias torna-se transitória**.
Usamos então o **verbo estar**:

- O cinema ainda está longe, ainda demoramos meia hora a chegar.
- A ponte está perto, abranda que é estreita.
- (No caso do hotel, "[o caminho para] o hotel é por ali", não vejo como construir isso num formato transitório/de movimento.)
- A [biblioteca móvel](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblioteca_m%C3%B3vel) costuma parar junto à Câmara Municipal, mas hoje está perto do Bar do Óscar.

Comment: Como sempre, agradeço sugestões comentários e críticas construtivas! :) Força, equipa de peer-review, escrutinai-me que estou a contar convosco! ❤

Comment: Talvez seja uma situação rebuscada, mas um exemplo em que vejo "está" funcionando no exemplo do hotel é o seguinte. --- Pessoa A: Essa região da cidade não é importante para nós. Pessoa B: Como não? O [nosso] hotel está ali. Pessoa A: Claro, mas falo importante de visitar.

Comment: Interessante, @stafusa , eu acho que usaria "Como não? O [nosso] hotel é lá." Suponho que são diferenças regionais.

Comment: Sim pode ser. Outra possibilidade é, apesar do hotel estar permanentemente no local, ele é "seu" hotel temporariamente apenas...